# Multiple JLists on one JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am making a program that prints out the items on a JList and am trying to use the least memory possible. Therefore, I only want to use one JList variable but still have two lists on the screen that I can read from. I have come in to problems in finding how to find values in the first list that I initialize and add to the JPanel.

JPanel initialization method:

```
public  void run() {
    panel = new JPanel(null);
    //Initalize components

    //List 1
    ArrayList<String> st = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) st.add("Number: " + i);
    jli = new JList(st.toArray());
    jli.setName("MyList1");
    jli.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jli.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    jli.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    jli.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jli);
    jsp.setSize(new Dimension(120, 130));
    jsp.setLocation(5, 5);
    panel.add(jsp);

    //List 2
    st = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) st.add("#: " + i);
    jli = new JList(st.toArray());
    jli.setName("MyList2");
    jli.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jli.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    jli.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    jli.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    jsp = new JScrollPane(jli);
    jsp.setSize(new Dimension(120, 130));
    jsp.setLocation(150, 5);
    panel.add(jsp);

    //Button 1
    jb = new JButton("Print 1");
    jb.addActionListener(this);
    jb.setLocation(5, 140);
    jb.setSize(jb.getPreferredSize());
    panel.add(jb);

    //Button 2
    jb = new JButton("Print 2");
    jb.addActionListener(this);
    jb.setLocation(120, 140);
    jb.setSize(jb.getPreferredSize());
    panel.add(jb);
}
```

ActionPreformed Method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "Print 1":
            //This is where I need help
            break;
        case "Print 2":
            System.out.println(jli.getSelectedValue());
            break;
    }
}
```

In short, How do I find data from the first JList created and the Second JList created without making two JList variables?

Comment: Using a single "variable" while you have two instances of JList isn't going to save you any memory. You could have 10 variables pointing to the two lists and the increase in memory would insignificant...

Comment: Is the micro amount of memory from an extra JList really that harmful? Why is this a requirement?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the question offtopic is what are you doing awake at 5 am, related to the question use anonymous class then you don't have to do `switch`

Comment: @nachokk 20 month old = early mornings; I don't think the switch is to much of an issue, but I'd prefer to use an Action, but that's me

Comment: I try to code with the minimum number of variables possible because it makes the text look less cluttered. I am looking to keep my "style" and only have one variable for each type of component as opposed to having multiple variables for only one type of component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I find it pretty weird, but if you insist on having only one variable of each type, then you will have no direct access to the first instantiated list. Assuming your `panel` and `jli` are defined globally, you can find the list by searching the child components of the `panel`:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            // child component must be a JList, but not jli
            if(component instanceof JList && !component.equals(jli)) {
                JList firstList = (JList) component;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would still like to repeat that this code is a complete overhead that can be simply eliminated by introducing another `JList` variable. Instead of accessing the list directly, you will have to search for it, consuming cpu time. Also, what would you do if you would have a third `JList`? You couldn't then distinct the two inaccessible `JList`s from each other. If you still insist on having one variable, consider using a `List` of `JList`s:

```
List<JList> allMyJLists = new LinkedList<>();
JList jli = new JList(); // first JList
allMyJLists.add(jli);
jli = new JList(); // second JList
allMyJLists.add(jli);
```

Now access first `JList` with

```
allMyJLists.get(0);
```

and the second one with

```
allMyJLists.get(1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I like the idea of having a "List of Lists"